# How to handle data concurrency in web applications with rest API Django/Spring

Tags: django, database, web-applications, concurrency, rest

How is data concurrency handled in web applications, does it have something to do with multi threading, I have developed a few web applications but didn't came across this problem until now.

An audio file on my website has 10 plays
If 50 people play the audio  at the same time, how do I ensure that the play count is now 60 and not 11.

Which technology should be used for this kind of problem , is it possible with Django (rest api) ? If yes how ?

I'm an amateur all criticism is welcome.

Comment: It'd be good if you mentioned the database you're using and whether there's a framework that you're using,  that would help the question.  I'd let the database handle the concurrency. If you can get your framework to run SQL, then do something like `UPDATE video SET views = views +1 WHERE id = @id` - and pass in the video id as a parameter. Database engines have had  LOT of clever people put time into handling concurrency.

Comment: Django framework, MongoDb / sql any one would fo

Comment: I let the database handle the concurrency thing, but the HR asked me in interview that if 50 people play a audio file at same time how will you handle it so the count is increased to +50 and not just +1